# How to refactor constructor-chaining in enable nullability context?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have old code base with constructor chaining which looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{   
    public Foo(string first, string second, string third)
    {
        this.First = first; 
        this.Second = second;
        this.Third = third;
    }

    public Foo(string first, string second) : this(first, second, null)
    {

    }
    public Foo(string first) : this(first, null)
    {
    }
    public string First { get; set; }

    public string Second { get; set; }

    public string Third { get; set; }
}
```

I added the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` setting, so as to protect the code from `NullReferenceException`.

As you can imagine when calling from a constructor with less parameters a constructor with more parameters and passing null - I get a warning on passing null that "Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type."

One solution I see is to keep just 1 constructor with all nullable parameters and default values to null. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Just make the types of `Second` and `Third`  and their parameters nullable.

Comment: If your intent is to guard against NREs, why are you allowing the object to come into being with `null` values for properties you've explicitly declared not to be nullable?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, as mentioned this is old code base. Before nullable reference types, this is how constructor chaining was done. You didn't have the opportunity to declare a reference type as nullable.

Comment: Constructor chaining isn't the issue here. The fact that it's possible to do `new Foo(first)` means it's legal to have a `Foo` where `Second` and `Third` are `null`. If this is *intended*, they should just be declared nullable (`string? Second`). If this is *not* intended, the code needs to be changed, potentially breaking clients. If you instead want to keep this code as-is without having to add nullable declarations (but also without warnings for potential NREs), just compile it in a `#nullable disable` context (as NRTs can be flexibly opted in or out of).

Comment: Jeroen, yes, I agree. Obviously, they were intended to be null in some cases. @Sweeper, since you gave the answer first, if you want you can post your opinion as an answer to that I can choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is possible for `Second` and `Third` to have the value `null` by calling the constructors with fewer parameters, they are *nullable*, so you should mark them, and their corresponding parameters, as such. Change their type to `string?`:

```
public class Foo
{   
    public Foo(string first, string? second, string? third)
    {
        this.First = first; 
        this.Second = second;
        this.Third = third;
    }

    public Foo(string first, string? second) : this(first, second, null)
    {

    }
    public Foo(string first) : this(first, null)
    {
    }
    public string First { get; set; }

    public string? Second { get; set; }

    public string? Third { get; set; }
}
```